# How to run a code after click event triggers and page loads

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I am working on a web application where I have triggered click event via jquery. I also have a link id e.g "unit30" in a variable. so when click event is triggered, new page is loaded. so I have to find that id on the page and add class "active" to it.
what I have done right now is this

```
jQuery(document).on('click','.course_lesson a',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var href = $(this).attr('href');
var link = href.split("?")[1];
var unit = link.split("=")[1]; // this gives me id unit30
jQuery("input.course_button").trigger("click"); //click event is triggered and new page is loaded. now I have to find unit30 id on this page and add class "active" to it.
});
```

Comment: I don't see your question here or any issue. Is the problem finding element with that id? Or I don't get something here...

Comment: my problem occurs after the click event is triggerent. as I have mentioned in comments, after click event is triggered, new page loads. now how I can find the id and add class "active" to it. because page is loaded again and I am unable to add class active.

Comment: You can add some parameter in your browser on button click which is causing page load and then check that param val on each load to add active class

Comment: can you give me some example how to add parameter please